# Laravel 5 Config changes not getting updated

Tags: laravel-5

I have clone a project to different folder. I have change database in config/database.php in new project folder but both projects still use the same database.
I've try 'php artisan config:clear' and clear session folder, still not working.
What's confusing is it depends on which project I log in first. It will use database from that project.

Comment: Make changes in your `.env` file.

Comment: @VishalSh I already did that. Still not working.

Comment: remove those configs from `.env`. Ideally, in such a case laravel reads the config from `database.php`